# How To Get HREF Of Selected Anchor Text in TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have access to the selected text in TinyMCE via

```
var selection = parent.tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent();
```

but HOW do I have access to the href of selected piece of text that has already been linked? So if the text was hyperlinked to http://www.youtube.com then upon selection I can auto-populate the link box with http://www.youtube.com ... So I guess I'm looking for something like:

```
var href = href-of-my-selected-tinymce-text
```

Just for reference: I'm building a custom plug that call up and external custom dialog...

**Many thanks to anybody that can give me a heads up :)**

Comment: Can you show an actual string that gets stored as your `selection` variable? I would like to see what TinyMCE actually returns you with that `.getContents()` function call. I may have a solution ready for you...

Comment: Actually, I've figured it out. Answer coming shortly. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is parse the returned string from `getContent()` call as HTML! As you've tagged your post with jQuery, I assume using jQuery for this is desired. With that said, your solution to retrieving the `href` value of the `a` element within your TincyMCE selection, do the following:

```
// This value of var selectionFromTinyMCE is an example
// of what parent.tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent(); returns to you
var selectionFromTinyMCE = 'sit our <a href="../forum/index.php">community forum</a>! We also';

// Here we take the string returned by TinyMCE, wrap it with a span tag,
// and pass it into a jQuery. This forces jQuery to evaluate the string as HTML!
var $jStr = $("<span>"+selectionFromTinyMCE+"</span>");

// You then create new variable and store the value of the href attribute
// of the <a> element from within your string.
var hrefValueFromTinyMCEselection = $jStr.find("a").attr("href");

// Check the console to see the result below, outputted as a string
console.log( hrefValueFromTinyMCEselection );
```

Here's a JSFiddle version of the code above to see it happening live (open to console to see the results logged): http://jsfiddle.net/lasha/NF9V8/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pull just the bit you need (I'm extrapolating a Wordpress shortcode from a selected link);

```
selectedNode = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode();
selected= tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent();

if( selectedNode ){. // need to test for 'http'
    //Wrap shortcode around it.
    content =  '[button href="'+ selectedNode +'"]'+selected+'[/button]';

} else {
return false;
}
```

Comment: I have to say my knowledge of both Tinymce and Javascript are not sufficient to know why, when `selectedNode` is a daily complicated piece of HTML, it appears as a string in the output. Ie I can't use string functions to test if it is a URL.